# Right way to access the Google Cloud Storage bucket via Public API

Tags: curl, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying the following request to access the bucket by using curl, via the public API:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' -d @xxx.jpeg 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/clips.xxx.xxx/o?uploadType=media&name=x.jpeg&key=XXX'
```

With XXX being the generated key in the Public API.

However I'm getting an authorization failure:

> {
>    "error": {
>     "errors": [
>      {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "required",
>       "message": "Login Required",
>       "locationType": "header",
>       "location": "Authorization"
>      }
>     ],
>     "code": 401,
>     "message": "Login Required"
>    }
>   }

Seems the request is incorrect and does not pass the authorization key, any idea what would be the right form of the request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's your API key, not an authorization key. See [Authorization](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) in the documentation. You need to use OAuth.

Comment: Just to confirm, API allows to manipulate storage properties (permissions, metadata, etc...), but not actually upload and erase files? I followed this guide, thinking it will allow doing file manipulation as well: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing

Comment: Yes, you can do everything with the API, including uploading, downloading, and deleting. See [How To Upload](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload)

Comment: Seems I've missed something then - what for is the (Public) API key then, if (in contrary to OAuth) it doesn't allow uploading?

Comment: It identifies your application. Take a read through [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing)